# React-Native ListView correctly return empty row

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

how do i skip a row from being rendered in ListView. Following example works and is the normal way I would do that.

```
renderRow(rowData) {
  if (!rowData.foo) { return null; }

  return <View style={{ height: 100 }}><Text>{rowData.bar}</Text></View>
}
```

The problem about this is that onChangeVisibleRows does not get called as soon as 1 row is returning null.

Same result with

```
if (!rowData.foo) { return <View style={{ height: 0 }} />; }
```

while

```
if (!rowData.foo) { return <View style={{ height: 1 }} />; }
```

works fine, but is not a good solution.

So, my guess is that it is a ListView-Bug but is returning null really the correct way to skip rendering a row? I didn't found any other options yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter your data before setting into the DataSource:

```
dataSource.cloneWithRows(
   yourDataArray.filter(item => item.foo !== null)
);
```

Comment: Damn, that was foolish. Thanks!

Comment: Is it better to filter/sort on cloneWIthRows such as sorting by peoples names or in mapToState?

`this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(gigs);`

or

`const mapStateToProps = state => {
    
    const arrWithKeys = Object.keys(state.gigs || {}).map((uid) => {`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!rowData.foo) { return <View style={{ opacity: 0 }} />; }
```